# iOS Screen Capture / Recording

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

So in my app I am trying to "record" the screen using screenshots. It is imperative that I have these individual frames as images, as they are being modified and combined later on a server. Adding to this complexity, it is in a slow-paced game using Cocos2D. The way I am currently taking a screenshot is similar to how Apple recommends it in [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html).

Unfortunately, taking these screenshots at 12-15 FPS causes a crash on anything above an iPad 2. Because the pixel density of newer devices is so high, storing them in a buffer at 12-15 FPS causes memory to spike, which kills the app. Are there any suggested ways of rapidly taking screenshots on iOS devices?

I have explored the option of halving the pixels on newer devices, but this still requires that I save all individual pixels in a buffer somewhere. Can any other screenshot methods work with OpenGL views to screenshot, so that I am able to scale it down?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/wess/Glimpse It isn't for Cocoa2D, but it has some optimizations that may help.

Comment: Thanks @RyanPoolos. I'm going to try to adapt that to just give me individual images instead of writing to a movie. I also found another method that is promising. All I really need is something that can reduce the size of retina screenshots, if that exists.

Comment: I don't know if Glimpse is going to help you all that much, because it only captures UIImages from your views, just like you're doing now. I know you want to keep these as images, but storing uncompressed images in memory isn't a way to go on these devices. Recording this to video on disk may be your best bet, followed by an extraction of the frames from the video.

Comment: @BradLarson I have only ruled that method out because I'm sending these in real time to a server as they are taken. Maybe we will have to rethink our strategy and send them all at the end.. We're trying a radical system capturing face images and screen images and syncing them up to track eye movement. So far so good, aside from the retina display. I'm just worried that with a video, we will get out of sync.

Comment: you only need one buffer, save it to file, and reuse the buffer for the next shot

Answer (score 0):

There are some external frameworks and SKD's that can do that for you. I found https://www.kamcord.com/developers/, but I'm sure there are more options. Hope it helps!